# how to delete decimals in Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an output like

```
a = [1 1.4 2.45 2.22; 2 3 4.2 1]
```

and I need the output to be like

```
[1 1 2 2; 2 3 4 1]
```

I don't want to round it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fix maybe OK.
If you have both positive and negative numbers, and you just want to delete decimals, fix is a good choice.

> > b=[1 1.4 2.45 2.22; 2 3 -4.2 1]

b =

```
1.0000    1.4000    2.4500    2.2200
2.0000    3.0000   -4.2000    1.0000
```

> > fix(b)

ans =

```
 1     1     2     2
 2     3    -4     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [fix](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fix.html) rather than [round](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/round.html), e.g.

```
octave-3.4.0:1> a = [1 1.4 2.45 2.22; 2 3 4.8 1]
a =

   1.0000   1.4000   2.4500   2.2200
   2.0000   3.0000   4.8000   1.0000

octave-3.4.0:2> b = fix(a)
b =

   1   1   2   2
   2   3   4   1
```